# Error in Prisma connectOrCreate in nested create

Tags: mysql, graphql, prisma, mutation, resolver

I'm using GraphQL and Prisma to create a backend app. I have Publication, Version and Author models defined in Prisma. Each Publication can have many versions and each version belongs to one publication. Also there's a many-to-many relation between Version and Author. I'm trying to create the `createPublication` mutation as follow:

```
const { accessType, isPublished, tags, version } = args.input;

const publication = await prisma.publication.create({
  data: {
    accessType,
    isPublished,
    tags,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date(),
    versions: {
      create: [{
        versionNumber: version.versionNumber,
        title: version.title,
        abstract: version.abstract,
        authors: {
          connectOrCreate: version.authors.map((author) => {
            return {
              where: {
                firstName: author.firstName,
                middleName: author.middleName || null, // Since the middleName is option, I have set it to be null if not exsists in `where` clause.
                lastName: author.lastname,
              },
              create: {
                firstName: author.firstName,
                middleName: author.middleName,
                lastName: author.lastname,
              },
            }
          })
        },
      }],
    },
  },
)};
```

The Author model in Prisma is like:

```
model Author {
  id         String  @id @default(uuid())
  userId     String? @unique
  firstName  String
  middleName String?
  lastName   String

  user         User?                @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  versions     Version[]
}
```

The user field in Author model is for when an author is already a user of this app.

Running this code, I get the following error:

```
Types of property 'where' are incompatible.
Type '{ firstName: string; middleName: string; lastName: string; }' has no properties in 
common with type 'AuthorWhereUniqueInput'.
```

I can't figure out what is the problem. I'll appreciate any help.